# Calc Beginner Question

Tags: calculus

I am self teaching myself calculus  (http://calculusmadeeasy.org/6.html) and got to this:

I don't understand the division performed. Can anyone give some tips?

[Quotient Rule Long Division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7MXf.png)

Comment: Perhaps a better proof of the quotient rule is by using the product rule and chain rule as it is intuitive and easier to understand. I find the long division proof mentioned non-intuitive and weird in some way.

Comment: Never seen this before, but it's an interesting way to come up with the quotient rule. It is essentially same as (ordinary) long division of integers. I'll try to draw a picture

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Does this help? Each colour is one step in the long division algorithm.

That said, you should also read the proof by using product rule and chain rule, using $u \times \frac1v$.

Comment: This is great -  Thankyou Benjamin!